# Export children as root level objects

Tags: export, parent

In my blender scene I have several objects that are parented to an Empty. I use this Empty to move the objects around the scene without having to manually move each one. Works like a charm.

However when I export my scene and load it into my program, the child objects of my Empty are only accessible as nodes of the Empty as opposed to being their own reference-able objects.

Is there a way within blender to, upon export, make all child objects of Empty their own object?

Comment: I've been researching this more and what I might be wanting is a group of objects vs parenting to an empty. I will test this and post my results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue was in fact to remove the empty keeping the children (applying any transformations made using the parent), and then create a group of objects.

Creating a group of objects can be done by selecting each object you wish to have in the group and pressing `ctrl+g`. To select all objects in the group, simply select one object, press `shift+g`and select group.